# Disable 0db feature in a R9 380 OC STRIX graphics card in linux

Tags: linux, fan, cooling, amd-graphics-card, silent-cooling

Hello all I recently purchased a R9 380 OC STRIX asus graphics card and I noticed quickly after installing the card that when the system runs POST the graphics cards fans do not turn on which concerns / pretty much scares me greatly. I quickly found that the graphics card comes with 0db technology stopping the fans from running under a certain temperature threshold and I personally wish to test the fans because I don't see them working at POST and I generally just want maximum cooling. After doing some googling I found out that a Windows program (ASUS graphic tweak II) can control the graphics card but I primarily use linux and do not have a working Windows installation.

This leads me to three questions. Revolving around this issue:
1. If anyone knows this line or style of card activates its fans during POST.

2. Is there a way to access and control the fans in linux.
3. If the answer to question 2 is no could anyone tell me if the changes made by the windows program change the cards behavior when the program is not running and or I'm not using a Windows install. I have read conflicting information on web on whether this acts like a service or actually changes some value in the firmware

Comment: This seems to be a Radeon card. Which driver are you using? (Look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`). In general, fan control is a hairy issue, because every hardware manufacturer handles it differently. Both video drivers and utilities like `lmsensors` do *some* fan control, but it may or may not work for your hardware.

Comment: It is an amd card but uses the newer Amdgpu module over the older radeon one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for `amdgpu fan` finds [this](https://github.com/DominiLux/amdgpu-pro-fans) project. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/DominiLux/amdgpu-pro-fans/blob/master/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh), the kernel module exposes fan control on the `/sys` FS via the [hwmon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface) interface.

So you can either write directly to the `pwm*` files in

```
/sys/class/drm/card*/device/hwmon/hwmon*/
```

(with the correct path for your actual hardware, of course), like the script does, use the *lmsensors* package your distribution is sure to have, or use a script like the above or other program that does the control for you. The *hwmon* link above explains the files and the values you can write to them.

Given the kind of interface that is exposed, it's very likely that under Windows a driver controls the fans, so they are not "activated" during POST, and anything Windows does doesn't cause permanent changes. And "0db" is just a fancy name for the control in the driver. That's a guess, without having access to the source code of the Windows driver it's hard to say anything definite.

Comment: Thank you this was incredibly informative. The hwmon interface on my system was not exposed for my graphics card as my kernel was too old.

Comment: However if I may ask a follow up question. I still have run into a snag and I am not sure how exactly to fix the situation. The temp_crit and temp_crit_hyst variables are not being populated. My thoughts were perhaps I did not compile the correct I2C module however I am not sure exactly how to probe my hardware to find the I2C chip my card uses. I tried I2C-probe but I did not find a result. I can not definitively say however that the tool was at fault over my ignorance on the subject

Comment: It may or may not be an I2C chip, it could also be driven from the GPU, and the amdgpu driver may contain code to handle both external chips and internal registers for the fan. The `/sys` files may have some hint as to what the sitation is for your hardware in form of symlinks to other subsystems, but I'd have to see the tree to comment on that. Also, temp_crit is an optional entry, so I'd assume the driver did the right thing, and that information just isn't available.